# Как заставить работать SearchView.setOnCloseListener?

Tags: java, android, listener, методы, android-search-view

Требуется в коде отследить закрытие строки поиска — `SearchView`. Открытие отслеживаю с помощью `setOnSearchClickListener`, данный метод не вызывает проблем, но отслеживание закрытия не работает. Ниже приведен код слушателя для закрытия `SearchView`:

```
searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Закрыто", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

В интернете нашел примеры с использованием методов `onMenuItemActionExpand` и `onMenuItemActionCollapse`, но это не то, что нужно. Можете подсказать как сделать нормальный слушатель закрытия `SearchView` с помощью метода, представленного в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setOnCloseListener(android.widget.SearchView.OnCloseListener)) Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убетитесь что у вашего меню item-a выставлен атрибут `app:showAsAction="always"`, должно быть так

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```